# Error message when picture upload field is empty

Tags: php

How can make picture upload required on HMS testimonial module?

Here the code bribe about that field :

---

```
if (isset($_FILES['hms_testimonials_image']) && ($_FILES['hms_testimonials_image']['size'] > 0) && $settings['form_show_upload'] == 1) {

$get_file_type = wp_check_filetype( basename($_FILES['hms_testimonials_image']['name'] ) );
$uploaded_type = $get_file_type['type'];

if (!in_array($uploaded_type, $allowed))
$errors[] = apply_filters('hms_testimonials_sc_error_image', __('You have uploaded an invalid file type.', 'hms-testimonials') );

}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if no files uploaded using,

```
count($_FILES);
```

Above code will return 0 in case user have not uploaded any files.

---

If there are multiple file upload handling and you want to check for specific filed, You can use [is_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to ensure file upload of specific field.

Like this,

```
if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filed_name"]['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "Error: File not uploaded";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, please do up-vote or accept answer if it will help you.

Comment: `count($_FILES);` will only return 0 if the submitted form has no file fields. If the form has a file field but no file was uploaded, the `$_FILES` superglobal will still be filled with the file field, but with `error` set to `4`.

Comment: I used : if(empty($_FILES['hms_testimonials_image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['hms_testimonials_image']['tmp_name'])) ..